# How to refactor this table of objects to be sorted?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the basics of what is currently written:

```
$scope.data = {};
var data = $http.get(array of objects from server);
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  $scope.data[data[i]._id] = data[i];
}
```

then I'm building a table of the data like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td>{{ data.timestamp }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.activity }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.location }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.customer }}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="completeAction(data._id)">Complete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then in completeAction it POSTS to the server that the id has been completed, and when it gets a 200 status back from the post it does:

```
delete $scope.data[id];
```

This all works fine, but I wanted to be able to sort the data in the table a specific way;  first by Activity, then by Time.  I found a code snippet from https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js  that let's me sort the data array from the server just fine, but obviously that doesn't work for the $scope.data since it's an object rather than array.

So I tried converting $scope.data into an array and doing something like this:

```
$scope.data = [];
var data = $http.get(array of objects from server);
var s = firstBy("activity")
        .thenBy("time");
data.sort(s);
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for (var j = 0; j<$scope.data.length; j++) {
    if ($scope.data[j]._id == data[i]._id)
      found = true;
  }
  if (!found) 
    $scope.data.push(data[i]);
}
```

This works too.  My table is sorted the way I want it now.  The problem then becomes that I don't know how to delete things from the $scope when I push the button.  Since earlier I could just access the object to delete it by id, I'm not sure the best way to go about it now.  Plus I feel like there's bound to be a better way to do all of what I've done so far.  I'm just not much of a javascript developer :P

Hope I explained what I mean well enough.  If not, just let me know and I can try to be more specific.  Thanks for any help!

**edit to answer question:**

```
function completeAction(id) {
  $http.post(post to server with item id saying that it has been completed)
       .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 200) {
             delete $scope.data[id];
          }
       })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same sorting filtering by using angular `orderBy` filter to which you can pass `string` or array of `string` by which you wanted to sort an collection. Also use `as filteredData` after filtering where `filterData` will have all sorted collection of object. That you could access inside your controller by doing `$scope.filteredData`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: ['activity', 'time'] as filteredData">
```

> Be aware that, on larger collection using view level filter can affect
>   performance. I'd say that try to use it inside controller it
>   collection is larger like `$filter('orderBy')($scope.data,
>   ['activity', 'time'])`

---

**Update**

Its always to better to keep data update on view. I would say rather than handling a collection state on client side, you should make an another ajax call right after completing an action so that **data consistency** of application will be maintained.

Comment: Hmm, https://plnkr.co/edit/kBYR4cQHYRJpjsQ8raEv?p=preview

When that runs, it throws errors about $scope.friends not being an array.  So if I have to convert the object into an array first ot use the orderBy, then I'm still not sure how to get the correct one to remove from $scope when I'm finished.

Comment: @Keirathi I little confused now, why your are keeping `friends = {}` (object) and pushing element one by one rather do `$scope.friends = friends` and then `orderBy` will happen on view directly, here is [plunkr  in action](https://plnkr.co/edit/WXExWWBmXpkckUXOF4vO?p=preview)

Comment: Right, I know that.  That's the way it was written from the Angular orderBy documentation.  The problem is I'm trying to fit it into my code.  If I just plug '| orderBy etc' into my code it doesn't work since my $scope.data in an object.  If I keep $scope.data as an array instead of an object, I can't figure out how to delete things from $scope.data when I click the completeAction button.

Comment: Sorry if I'm still not being super clear.  What I mean is that I have separate problems.  If my $scope.data is an array, then I can sort it fine, but then I don't know how to delete items when I click on the completeAction(item._id) button in the table.  If my $scope.data is an object, then I can delete things with completeAction(item._id) fine, but I can't sort them.  I just can't figure out the right way to solve either one.

Comment: @Keirathi well, may I know what `completeAction` method does? I mean to say how can you say that action has been completed or not by looking at record? I guess you must be doing `activity` to `completed` or something like that

Comment: I editted the OP with the completeAction part how it is written currently for $scope.data being an object and deleting it by referencing the specific object by id.

Comment: @Keirathi oh.. this isn't a correct way to architect your application.. you shouldn't be doing such thing on client side only, like you were deleting array from client side directly.. what will happen after completing one of the record & suppose you deleted it from `$scope.data` collection, but if user reloads the page, he can see that record in `$scope.data` array on the view.. Ideally you should be maintain one column in your data table which will keep track of status, the value of status can be `In Progress, Some Step Name, Completed(or this can be varied based on requirement)

Comment: So when you make an ajax for `completeAction` just toggle that flag on server side & thereafter get the whole collection once again.

Comment: The server already has a STATUS, so in the first part when I request the data list, it already only has ones that are currently actively waiting for input.  Then when I push the button, it just deletes it from the view, and updates the record in the database to be COMPLETED so it doesn't get sent again.  I'm just trying to hide it from the view, really, once it is complete without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123077/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-keirathi).